# Prove inequality

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

I have to prove the following inequality (See Appendix A of Classical Fourier Analysis of Grafakos).
$$
\left(\frac{(1+s/y)^y}{e^s}\right)^{2y} \leq (1+s)^2 / \exp(s), \quad s\geq 0
$$
and
$$
\left(\frac{(1+s/y)^y}{e^s}\right)^{2y} \leq \exp(-s^2),\quad -y<s < 0.
$$
How can I prove this?

Comment: The first inequality fails to hold e.g. for $s=4$ and $y=1/10$.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

The first inequality fails to hold e.g. for $s=4$ and $y=1/10$.

The second inequality can be rewritten as
\begin{equation*}
    L(y)\le e^{-s^2} \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
if $-y<s<0$, where
\begin{equation*}
    L(y):=L(s,y):=\left(e^{-s} \left(\frac{s}{y}+1\right)^y\right)^{2 y}. 
\end{equation*}
We have
\begin{equation*}
    L_1(y):=\frac{L'(y)}{2 y}\,\left(e^{-s} \left(\frac{s+y}{y}\right)^y\right)^{-2 y}
    =2 \ln \left(\frac{s+y}{y}\right)-\frac{s (s+2 y)}{y (s+y)}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    L'_1(y)=\frac{s^3}{y^2 (s+y)^2}<0, \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
since $y>-s$ and $s<0$, so that $L_1$ is decreasing (on $(-s,\infty)$).
Also, $L_1(y)\to0$ as $y\to\infty$. So, $L_1>0$ and hence $L$ is increasing, to $e^{-s^2}$, as $y$ is increasing to $\infty$. So, \eqref{10} follows. This completes the proof of your second inequality. $\quad\Box$

---

Your first inequality was actually stated only for $y\ge1$ in that book (and $s\ge0$).
Then inequality \eqref{20} will turn to its opposite, $L'_1(y)\ge0$. So, here $L_1$ is nondecreasing, and still $L_1(y)\to0$ as $y\to\infty$.  So, $L_1<0$ and hence $L$ is decreasing. So,
\begin{equation}
    L\le L(1)=e^{-2 s} (1 + s)^2\le (1+s)^2 / \exp(s). \quad\Box 
\end{equation}

Comment: Are your equations numbered according to the [BASIC line-numbering convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_number#Line_numbers_and_style)?

Comment: @LSpice : I didn't know it was the BASIC convention, but I thought it would be convenient for MO, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

For the second inequality, write $t:=-s$, then $y>t>0$ and we need to prove that
$$
(1-t/y)^y \leq \exp{\left\{-\frac{t^2}{2y}-t\right\}}.
$$
Taking logarithms of both sides and denoting $t/y=:\alpha \in (0, 1)$ we get an equivalent inequality
$$
\log{(1-\alpha)}\leq -\alpha^2/2-\alpha,
$$
which follows from the Taylor series expansion of the function $\log{(1-x)}$.